# How do I handle IDisposable's inside a Result in F#?

Tags: f#

I want to return an `HttpResponseMessage`, which implements `IDisposable`, within a `Result` (or any other discriminated union). However, since `Result` itself is not IDisposable, I can't `use!` it like I would for the disposable object itself. What do I do? Can I implement my own DU called `DisposableResult` that implements `IDisposable` itself?

Below is an example of what I mean. `crawlStuff` asynchronously returns `Result<HttpResponseMessage, string>`. I can't `use!` the result, leading to a memory leak unless I manually release it.

```
open System.Net.Http

let crawlStuff (client : HttpClient) : Async<Result<HttpResponseMessage, string>> = 
    async {
        // res is HttpResponseMessage which implements IDisposable
        let! res = client.GetAsync("https://ifconfig.me") |> Async.AwaitTask
        return
            if res.IsSuccessStatusCode then
                Ok res
            else
                Error "Something wrong"
    } 

async {
    use client = new HttpClient()

    // Memory leak because result it could carry HttpResponseMessage.
    // I want to use! here, but can't because Result<> is not IDisposable
    let! response = crawlStuff client

    printfn "%A" response
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can implement your own disposable result type, like this:

```ml
type DisposableResult<'t, 'terr when 't :> IDisposable> =
     | DOk of 't
     | DError of 'terr

     interface IDisposable with
          member this.Dispose() =
               match this with
                    | DOk value -> value.Dispose()
                    | _ -> ()
```

Usage would then be:

```ml
open System.Net.Http

let crawlStuff (client : HttpClient) : Async<Result<HttpResponseMessage, string>> = 
    async {
        // res is HttpResponseMessage which implements IDisposable
        let! res = client.GetAsync("https://ifconfig.me") |> Async.AwaitTask
        return
            if res.IsSuccessStatusCode then
                DOk res
            else
                DError "Something wrong"
    } 

async {
    use client = new HttpClient()
    use! response = crawlStuff client
    printfn "%A" response
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the part I was missing was the `when 't :> IDisposable` part to restrict the type. Marking as answer, although the other answer by @JL0PD is very cool too.

Answer (score 6):

I would've create wrapper around `Result`, that will dispose underlying values:

```ml
let (|AsDisposable|) x =
    match box x with
    | :? IDisposable as dis -> ValueSome dis
    | _ -> ValueNone

type ResultDisposer<'v, 'e> =
    struct
        val Result : Result<'v, 'e>
        new res = { Result = res }
        interface IDisposable with
            member r.Dispose() =
                match r.Result with
                // | Ok (:? IDisposable as dis) // causes FS0008, so we have to hack
                | Ok (AsDisposable (ValueSome dis))
                | Error (AsDisposable (ValueSome dis)) -> dis.Dispose()
                | _ -> ()
    end

type Result<'a, 'b> with
    member r.AsDisposable = new ResultDisposer<'a, 'b>(r)
```

And use it this way

```ml
async {
    use client = new HttpClient()
    let! response = crawlStuff client
    use _ = response.AsDisposable

    printfn "%A" response
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This solution avoids need to rewrite existing code to `DisposableResult` and avoids allocations when disposable value is reference type, like in case of `HttpResponseMessage`. But decompilation shows that F# boxes `ResultDisposer`, even though it shouldn't :(